# Site Time Zone = field time zone but != database time zone

Tags: datetime

My site time zone setting under Admin>config>regional... is set to Chicago time.

My field date setting is set to use my site time zone.

My user account is set to Chicago, but when I look at the database, it is recording my time as a totally different time zone.

What am I missing? I really need to resolve an issue with Drupal resource-conflict module and the fact that my all-day events don't conflict with my hourly events. There is a topic here - https://www.drupal.org/node/2270533, but I can't seem to get my dates straitened out to even try it. Anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal and expected. When you look in the DB, the [Date API contrib](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module saves them as **[UTC time](https://www.google.ca/search?q=UTC%20time&oq=UTC%20time&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61j69i59j69i60.1144j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**.

Drupal then fetches your Unix time UTC value, and converts it to your time zone.

Comment: Here is what shows up in my database for example when I look at phpmyadmin on the datetime. 2016-04-24 04:00:00

Comment: @RobAdams forget what I said earlier. Looks like the Date API contrib module saves them like that.

Answer (score 1):

When entering data into the field, the data entered is assumed to be in the site's time zone. When the data is saved to the database, it is converted to UTC. When retrieved from the database, the data is converted to the Site's time zone for anonymous users or the User's time zone for logged in users when User-configurable time zones is enabled.
More info https://www.drupal.org/node/767182

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have to set my field widget to "no time zone conversion" in order to address my primary issue which is the resource-conflict detection not working on all-day events. When I do that, it screws up my dates on my reservation calendar. Is there a work-around for that?